# Is there anything else to clear besides browser cache?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

Im trying to view [THIS](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/index.html) on my google chrome browser (Version 37.0.2062.124 m), and for some reason, the animation isnt following the cursor like it does on other browsers. There's nothing wrong with the code since it seems to be working on chrome on my other PC too.

I've tried to Clear everything on the cache, deleted my temp file and flushed my DNS, both in Windows and Chrome, but its not working. Is there anything else I can clear?

Comment: ya work fine with me too

Comment: Yep it does work on my other PC too. What Im asking tho is what could I do to fix it? I've tried all the stuff above.

Comment: maybe you got some malware preventing the default behaviour of mousemove

Comment: GOt it to work, it seemed that the script stops working when the cpu and/or memory usage is high. Is there a such a feature on chrome?